# Why HTML SVG hexagon onClick "hitbox" being rectangular?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

I am trying to draw a board composed with hexagons using only HTML and CSS.
It's a React app.

My problem is with the "hitbox" of these hexagons being rectangular. Is there a way to have my `onClick` hitbox to perfectly fit my hexagons?

React.JS code:

```html
<div className={`land${getClassNames(landState)}`}>
<svg
  viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  version="1.1"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    
>
  <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"
  onClick={() => handleClick(index, selectLand, landState)} />
</svg>
```

CSS

```css
.land {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -32px;
  width: 140px;
}
.land svg {
  width: 100%;
}
.land.isVacant svg {
  fill : #e0e0e0;
}
.land.isOccupiedByPlayer1 svg {
  fill : #90caf9;
}
.land.isOccupiedByPlayer2 svg {
  fill : #ef9a9a;
}
.active svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Moving the `onClick` on the `polygone` gave me a beter result, but still not perfect and strange. I highlighted the unclickable zone on the following image. I don't understant this.

[image]

```css
.board {
    float: left; width: 1200px;
}

.land-row {
    clear: left;
}
.land-row.three {
    margin-left: 135px;
}
.land-row.four {
    margin-left: 67px;
}
.land {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-bottom: -32px;
    width: 140px;
}

.land svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.land.isVacant svg {
    fill : #e0e0e0;
}

.land.isOccupiedByPlayer1 svg {
    fill : #90caf9;
}

.land.isOccupiedByPlayer2 svg {
    fill : #ef9a9a;
}

.active svg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}



**EDIT:**<br>
```

```html
<div id="root"><div class="App"><div class="board"><div class="land-row three"><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div></div><div class="land-row four"><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer1"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div></div><div class="land-row"><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div></div><div class="land-row four"><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer1"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div></div><div class="land-row three"><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div><div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer2"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Same as @ksav I am not able to reproduce what you describe. Which browser, which version have you tested with? Are there other CSS rules applied to the `<svg>` element? Does the click behavior change when you remove the `filter` property?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I updated my question. Do you have the same result?

Comment: I just tested and it does it only when there's a hexagon under the hexagon I am clicking... Could it be another element getting in the way?

Comment: @Boubou, yes, some invisible elements can be there. Please copy your code from the browser in developer window (BUT NOT your React.JS code).

Comment: @Bharata I added a code snippet with the html and css. I also tried to remove the margin-bottom: -32px rule and it works well without it (despite the fact the elements are not placed how I want. So I get that an element get in the way, but don't know how to avoid it...

Comment: Hey @Boubou, did you make more progress on your html game? I'd like to see how far you got.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All SVG elements are not rectangular. And your hexagon `polygon` is also not rectangular. In my demo below you will see it. On the following screenshot of my demo:

[image]

you can see some yellow and red points. If you click on this points (areas) in my demo (but not on screenshot!) then you will see that this elements are not rectangular.

### Interactive demo

```js
document.querySelector('svg').onclick = function(e)
{
    if(e.target.tagName == 'polygon')
        state.innerText = 'Congratulation! You clicked on polygon element.';
    else if(e.target.tagName == 'circle')
        state.innerText = 'You clicked on circle element.';
    else
        state.innerText = 'Bad result! You clicked on SVG, but NOT on polygon element.';
};
```

```html
<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="background:#048">
    <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="green"/>
</svg>
<div id="state"></div>
```

### UPDATE

Now you have added the HTML code and we can see your problem: you have for each `polygon` element one SVG wich is inside the `div` element. In the developer view it looks like on this screenshot:

[image]

Your `polygon` element is not rectangular, but it is inside the `div` element from class `land`. To solve this issue you can deactivate mouse events from `div.land` with `.board .land{pointer-events: none}` and because now mouse events from full `div` element (inclusive SVG with `polygon`) are deactivated you have to activate mouse events for `polygon` elements with `.board polygon{pointer-events: all}`. And after this CSS adding it works.

```js
document.querySelector('.board').onclick = function(e)
{
    if(e.target.tagName == 'polygon')
    {
        var parentDivCL = e.target.closest('.land').classList;
        if(parentDivCL.contains('isVacant'))
        {
            parentDivCL.remove('isActive', 'isVacant');
            parentDivCL.add('isOccupiedByPlayer1');
        }
    }
};
```

```css
.board .land{pointer-events: none}
.board polygon{pointer-events: all}

.board {
    float: left; width: 1200px;
}

.land-row {
    clear: left;
}
.land-row.three {
    margin-left: 135px;
}
.land-row.four {
    margin-left: 67px;
}
.land {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-bottom: -32px;
    width: 140px;
}

.land svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.land.isVacant svg {
    fill : #e0e0e0;
}

.land.isOccupiedByPlayer1 svg {
    fill : #90caf9;
}

.land.isOccupiedByPlayer2 svg {
    fill : #ef9a9a;
}

.active svg:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<div class="App">
<div class="board">

<div class="land-row three">
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="land-row four">
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer1">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="land-row">
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="land-row four">
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer1">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="land-row three">
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isActive isVacant">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer2">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing should be the default for click handlers attached to an SVG shape.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"
          onclick="console.log('You have clicked the polygon.')" />
</svg>
```

Update. Here is the same thing with your updated code, and some pointer-events properties added to the svgs, polygons and divs.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('polygon').forEach(polygon => {
  polygon.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.closest('.land').classList.add('isOccupiedByPlayer1')
  })
})
```

```css
.board {
  float: left;
  width: 1200px;
}

.land-row {
  clear: left;
}

.land-row.three {
  margin-left: 135px;
}

.land-row.four {
  margin-left: 67px;
}

.land {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-bottom: -32px;
  width: 140px;
}

.land svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.land.isVacant svg {
  fill: #e0e0e0;
}

.land.isOccupiedByPlayer1 svg {
  fill: #90caf9;
}

.land.isOccupiedByPlayer2 svg {
  fill: #ef9a9a;
}

.active svg:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div,
svg {
  pointer-events: none;
}

polygon {
  pointer-events: fill;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="App">
    <div class="board">
      <div class="land-row three">
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
      </div>
      <div class="land-row four">
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer1"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
      </div>
      <div class="land-row">
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
      </div>
      <div class="land-row four">
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer1"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
      </div>
      <div class="land-row three">
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isActive isVacant"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
        <div class="land isOccupiedByPlayer2"><svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><polygon points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"></polygon></svg></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question, you can also see my comments. Thanks!

Comment: @ksav, «+1». But if you want to earn more points you have to learn add more description about what you do and why. And I would also expand the code snippet because not all people know how to see it and some people can not see this link.

Comment: @ksav, I do not understand why you have unupvoted my answer? And did you seen that OP was already online and he got the system message about the update from your answer? Do you think that he could have understand what you have done and why? And do you think that anybody who does not understand it will upvote and / or accept your answer?

Comment: I first though you were repeating what was posting.. Second snipet is on spot. Thanks for your help and time, upvoted